# How to make a type for arguments accepted by the method in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a method whose structure is given below.

```
const a = function (...args: any[]) {
  console.log(args);
}
```

as you can see in the structure of the function, the type of `args` is  `any[]`, I want to make a specific type for argument array accepted by the method.
How can I make a specific type for arguments accepted by the method in Typescript?
NOTE: The function  `a` can accept any type of argument like
`a(1, 2, 4, 5, 'asgasg', 124.52, { name: 'sparsh' });`

I want to make a specific type for arguments accepted by the method in Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom type:

`type x = string | number`

and in a case to fit your example:

```
type User = {
  name: string;
}

type x = string | number | User;

function a(...args: x[]){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `any[]` which would allow any property access including potentially invalid ones, one can use `unknown[]`.
Using `unknown[]` would allow passing any type of arguments, but will not disable type checking for property access etc. For example:

```
const a = function (...args: unknown[]) {
  console.log(args);
// console.log(args[0].toString); //disallowed by type checking 
  if(typeof args[0] === 'number') console.log(args[0].toFixed()) //allowed
}

a(2,3,4,5,6,7,"asds"); //ok
```